# Oracle Query Join issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have an Oracle table as shown below

```
Orders
---------
ORDERID
DESCRIPTION
TOTALVALUE
ORDERSTATUS
```

I have the below mentioned query

```
select ORDERID,ORDERSTATUS
FROM ORDERS
WHERE ORDERID IN( 1000,1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010,1020,
                  1030,104,1040,1090,789)
```

Some `orderIDs` mentioned above are not in orders table. In spite of that I want the orderIDs to appear in the resultset with status as null.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do an outer join to accomplish something like this :

```
SELECT ORDERID, ORDERSTATUS
FROM (
SELECT 1000 AS ORDERID FROM dual UNION SELECT 1001 FROM dual -- etc
) tmpOrderid
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERS O
    ON tmpOrderid.ORDERID = O.ORDERID;
```

I have never used Oracle, but there is most likely a function that can generate numbers (for exemple, generate_series(1000, 1010) in PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 7):

What about this:

```
SELECT T.COLUMN_VALUE AS ORDERID, ORD.ORDERSTATUS
FROM TABLE(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(
        1000,1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010,1020,1030,104,1040,1090,789
    )) T
LEFT JOIN ORDERS ORD ON ORD.ORDERID = T.COLUMN_VALUE;
```

You can also get it to work if the order IDs aren't fixed but a parameter. But the solution depends on whether you call the statement from PL/SQL or from another programming language such as C#, Java, PHP etc.

**Update**:
*SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST* is just a table type that's already defined in Oracle. You could use your own type:

```
CREATE TYPE NUMBER_TABLE_T AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CTE` as table for the `orderIds` (or store them into a temporary table), and [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_joins) your `Orders`:

```
With tmp As (
  Select 1000 As orderId From dual
  Union All
  Select 1001 From dual
  Union All
  ...
)
Select tmp.orderId, o.orderStatus
From tmp
Left Join orders o On ( o.orderId = tmp.orderId )
```

`orderStatus` is `NULL`, when no order is found.

Answer (score 0):

there is one more trick in oracle.

```
SELECT LEVEL + 1000 dt FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < (2000 - 1000)
```

it generates a recordset with 1000 rows which might be left joined with your table.